# Solving non linear second order ODE

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I am stuck here correcting my code.. I have a second order non linear differential equation for relativistic motion to solve and i cannot find a solution.
This is what I have tried so far :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint


def f(y, t, params):
    v, a = y      # unpack current values of y
    e, E, tau, m = params  # unpack parameters
    gamma = (1-(v/c)**2)**(1/2)
    derivs = [a,      # list of dy/dt=f functions
             -((((gamma**2)*theta+1)/(tau*(gamma**5)))*a)+((e*E)/(tau*(gamma**6)*m))-(6*(gamma**2)*v*(a**2))]
    return derivs

# Parameters
tau = 6*10**-24         # Given values
E = 10**6         # electric field
e = 1.602*10**-19     # electron charge
m = 9.109*10**-31 #electron mass
c = 1
#gamma = (1-(v/c)**2)**(1/2)

# Initial values
v0 = 0.0     # initial angular displacement
a0 = 0.0     # initial angular velocity

# Bundle parameters for ODE solver
params = [e, E, tau, m]

# Bundle initial conditions for ODE solver
y0 = [v0, a0]

# Make time array for solution
tStop = 0.2
tInc = 0.05
t = np.arange(0., tStop, tInc)

t = 0
dt = 0.0001
while v0 < 0.99 :
    t+= dt
    v0+= t
    v=v0
    print(t,v)

# Call the ODE solver
v = odeint(f, y0, t, args=(params,))

while v.all() < 0.99 :
  tStop = t + dt
  print(t, tStop, v)

# Plot results
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(8,8))

# Plot theta as a function of time
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax1.plot(t, v[:,0])
ax1.set_xlabel('time')
ax1.set_ylabel('v')

# Plot omega as a function of time
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(312)
ax2.plot(t, v[:,1])
ax2.set_xlabel('time')
ax2.set_ylabel('a')

# Plot a vs v
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(313)
twopi = 2.0*np.pi
ax3.plot(v[:,0]%twopi, v[:,1], '.', ms=1)
ax3.set_xlabel('v')
ax3.set_ylabel('a')
ax3.set_xlim(0., twopi)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Also the original problem is to find the time where v = 0.99c
given this ODE :

4. Consider the motion of an electron that is initially at rest in a uniform electric field of
   magnitude E = 106 V/m. The relativistic equation of motion is :

```
(/m) − τ /dt (6 /dt) = /dt ()
```

Where=02 =6×10−24 6

a) How long does it take for the electron to reach v = 0.99c?
b) Graph the velocity as a function of time in both linear and log plots.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: What do you mean by 'cant find a solution'?  We like to help debug code, but we need some idea of what is wrong.  If an error, a full traceback helps.  What runs and what doesn't?  I'd also suggest omitting all the plotting code for now, assuming that's not where the error occurs.  In other words, focus your question.  General questions get general answers, if any.

Comment: What are the two while-loops supposed to do? Your `odeint` call looks fine at first view, but it seems like you've having trouble extracting the point where you hit the desired velocity.

Comment: Consider using [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) instead (as is recommended in the `odeint` documentation) and defining an event at which your velocity is reached. This way the solver will automatically stop when the event happens, giving you your desired information.